# protractor and tricky accordion

Tags: javascript, css, testing, protractor

I have to select an element in what appears to be a pop up window, but in real live it is an accordion. I using the following approach, which is working:

```
var accordion = element(by.id('promoAccordion'));

var promoChannels = element.all(by.repeater('channelCreatives in creativesByChannel'));

var firstPromoChannel = element.all(by.repeater('channelCreatives in creativesByChannel')).first();
```

later on:

```
this.activatePromotions = function() {

expect((accordion).isPresent()).toBe(true);

expect(promoChannels.count()).toBeGreaterThan(1);

firstPromoChannel.click();
```

Now, I need to scroll down to "Send Changes" button and click on it. This button is defined as

```
var sendChangesButton = element(by.buttonText('Send Changes'));
```

The problem is that once I clicked on firstPromoChannel, it resulted appearance of the second vertical scroll bar (as content in accordion does not fit in the page). When I am trying

```
expect((accordion).isPresent()).toBe(true);

browser.executeScript('window.scrollBy(0,450);');
```

it actually scrolls down the original window which doesn't help me to get the button in view. there is no way to switch via `browser.switchTo();` or `browser.selectWindow();` as this is an accordion and not a new window.

How could I scroll down within this accordion to get the button in view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also use

```
browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', sendChangesButton.getWebElement());
```

Comment: Thank you very much, both posted solutions worked... I used "scrollIntoView" method to avoid dependency on coords...  I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this as follows;

```
var sendChangesButton = element(by.buttonText('Send Changes'));

browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollTop(450);', sendChangesButton.getWebElement());
```

Then this button clickable via protractor.